# Android ScrollView Not Scrolling Correctly

Tags: android-layout, android

I've been making my way through thenewboston's android tutorials and I'm stuck on number 35. There is supposed to be a scroll bar that takes up a weight of 30 at the top of the app. There are 6 textview/edittext field groups in the code, but I deleted 5 for simplicity. My problem is that all of the text and text boxes appear on the page and are not confined to the given weight (they all just show up on the page).  Has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix it?

Please, I'm new to stackoverflow. If you think this is a stupid question, please explain to me why and how I can ask it better.

Here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQCE.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you use weights, you always want to set the height or width to zero depending on the orientation of the parent component. Try setting heights to zero for your scrollview and the remaining containers as well (linear layouts and AnalogClock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Couple of things,

1. TheNewBoston made a mistake. Whenever you use weights you need
   to set the height (or width) of that element to 0dp. I've changed
   that in your code.
2. You shouldn't rely on the xml tool that eclipse has, you should always try to launch your app to some type of a device (emulator or preferably hardware)
3. I think by ScrollBar, you mean ScrollView? Because you're not doing anything to control the appearance of the scroll bar right now.
4. The parent of your layout (in this case) should match_parent, not wrap. (this is your main issue)
5. Also, you don't really need weightSum, android will just sum all the weights anyway.

   ```
   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="30" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="TextView" />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/editText1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:ems="10" >
           </EditText>

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="40"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Button" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="30"
       android:orientation="vertical" >


       <AnalogClock
           android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Tweaking those last few things and running it in the virtual android worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the views to 0dp if you are using weight. match_parent is causing problems. Also set the height of root view to match_parent. Try this, if I add many EditText's to the LinearLayout in the ScrollView it seems to give the effect you are after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="100">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10">
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```