# My ScrollView is not scrolling - how to solve?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

My scollview is not scrolling. I tried putting the scrollView inside a linear layout but still not working. I am trying the scroll view in landscape mode.Also bonus question, is there a layout that i can wrap my code into so that i can have my app be perfect on all screen sizes from small screen to big tablets.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/numbers1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NUMBERS"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/family1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FAMILY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/number"
        android:background="@color/category_home"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/colors1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="COLORS"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:background="@color/category_home"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/nouns1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VERBS"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/verbs1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOUNS"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/phrases1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PHRASES"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ScrollView Not Scrolling Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476637/android-scrollview-not-scrolling-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as per your layout use **`HorizontalScrollView`**

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NUMBERS"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorRed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FAMILY"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/number"
            android:background="@color/colorRed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="COLORS"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:background="@color/colorRed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VERBS"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NOUNS"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:background="@color/colorRed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PHRASES"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```